# Add time delay to javascript popup

Tags: javascript

I'm using the popular [CoverPop.js](http://coverpopjs.com/) script to generate a simple javascript lightbox popup on my page. However, the author did not add a built in setting to adjust the time delay for how long until the popup displays on the page (for example: 500ms, 1000ms, etc.). Is there a way to easily modify the script to allow me to add a time delay as such?

```
 /*!
 * CoverPop 2.1
 * http://coverpopjs.com
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Tyler Pearson
 * Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

(function (CoverPop, undefined) {
'use strict';

// set default settings
var settings = {

        // set default cover id
        coverId: 'CoverPop-cover',

        // duration (in days) before it pops up again
        expires: 30,

        // close if someone clicks an element with this class and prevent default action
        closeClassNoDefault: 'CoverPop-close',

        // close if someone clicks an element with this class and continue default action
        closeClassDefault: 'CoverPop-close-go',

        // change the cookie name
        cookieName: '_CoverPop',

        // on popup open function callback
        onPopUpOpen: null,

        // on popup close function callback
        onPopUpClose: null,

        // hash to append to url to force display of popup
        forceHash: 'splash',

        // hash to append to url to delay popup for 1 day
        delayHash: 'go',

        // close if the user clicks escape
        closeOnEscape: true,

        // toggle console.log statements
        debug: false
    },


    // grab the elements to be used
    $el = {
        html: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
        cover: document.getElementById(settings.coverId),
        closeClassDefaultEls: document.querySelectorAll('.' + settings.closeClassDefault),
        closeClassNoDefaultEls: document.querySelectorAll('.' + settings.closeClassNoDefault)
    },


    /**
     * Helper methods
     */

    util = {

        hasClass: function(el, name) {
            return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name + '(\\s|$)').test(el.className);
        },

        addClass: function(el, name) {
            if (!util.hasClass(el, name)) {
                el.className += (el.className ? ' ' : '') + name;
            }
        },

        removeClass: function(el, name) {
            if (util.hasClass(el, name)) {
                el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name + '(\\s|$)'), ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            }
        },

        addListener: function(target, type, handler) {
            if (target.addEventListener) {
                target.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
            } else if (target.attachEvent) {
                target.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
            }
        },

        removeListener: function(target, type, handler) {
            if (target.removeEventListener) {
                target.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
            } else if (target.detachEvent) {
                target.detachEvent('on' + type, handler);
            }
        },

        isFunction: function(functionToCheck) {
            var getType = {};
            return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
        },

        // for info and debugging
        shareInfo: function(message) {
            if (window.console && window.console.log && settings.debug) {
                window.console.log(message);
            }
        },

        setCookie: function(name, days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(+ date + (days * 86400000));
            document.cookie = name + '=true; expires=' + date.toGMTString() + '; path=/';
            util.shareInfo('Cookie ' + name + ' set for ' + days + ' days away.');
        },

        hasCookie: function(name) {
            if (document.cookie.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        // check if there is a hash in the url
        hashExists: function(hash) {
            if (window.location.hash.indexOf(hash) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        preventDefault: function(event) {
            if (event.preventDefault) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }
        },

        mergeObj: function(obj1, obj2) {
            for (var attr in obj2) {
                obj1[attr] = obj2[attr];
            }
        }
    },


    /**
     * Private Methods
     */

    // close popup when user hits escape button
    onDocUp = function(e) {
        if (settings.closeOnEscape) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                CoverPop.close();
            }
        }
    },

    openCallback = function() {

        // if not the default setting
        if (settings.onPopUpClose !== null) {

            // make sure the callback is a function
            if (util.isFunction(settings.onPopUpOpen)) {
                settings.onPopUpOpen.call();
                util.shareInfo('CoverPop is open.');
            } else {
                throw new TypeError('CoverPop open callback must be a function.');
            }
        }
    },

    closeCallback = function() {

        // if not the default setting
        if (settings.onPopUpClose !== null) {

            // make sure the callback is a function
            if (util.isFunction(settings.onPopUpClose)) {
                settings.onPopUpClose.call();
                util.shareInfo('CoverPop is closed.');
            } else {
                throw new TypeError('CoverPop close callback must be a function.');
            }
        }
    };



/**
 * Public methods
 */

CoverPop.open = function() {

    var i, len;

    if (util.hashExists(settings.delayHash)) {
        util.setCookie(settings.cookieName, 1); // expire after 1 day
        return;
    }

    util.addClass($el.html, 'CoverPop-open');

    // bind close events and prevent default event
    if ($el.closeClassNoDefaultEls.length > 0) {
        for (i=0, len = $el.closeClassNoDefaultEls.length; i < len; i++) {
            util.addListener($el.closeClassNoDefaultEls[i], 'click', function(e) {
                util.preventDefault(e);
                CoverPop.close();
            });
        }
    }

    // bind close events and continue with default event
    if ($el.closeClassDefaultEls.length > 0) {
        for (i=0, len = $el.closeClassDefaultEls.length; i < len; i++) {
            util.addListener($el.closeClassDefaultEls[i], 'click', CoverPop.close);
        }
    }

    // bind escape detection to document
    util.addListener(document, 'keyup', onDocUp);
    openCallback();
};

CoverPop.close = function() {
    util.removeClass($el.html, 'CoverPop-open');
    util.setCookie(settings.cookieName, settings.expires);

    // unbind escape detection to document
    util.removeListener(document, 'keyup', onDocUp);
    closeCallback();
};

CoverPop.init = function(options) {
    util.mergeObj(settings, options);

    // check if there is a cookie or hash before proceeding
    if (!util.hasCookie(settings.cookieName) || util.hashExists(settings.forceHash)) {
        CoverPop.open();
    }
};

// alias
CoverPop.start = function(options) {
    CoverPop.init(options);
};


}(window.CoverPop = window.CoverPop || {}));
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify how the plugin works. You can instead call it by making a delay, by using setTimeout, which accepts a callback function to be run after certain milliseconds.

Like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // call the plugin here
},1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
```